# Start animation after another animation (CSS/HTML)

Tags: html, css, animation

I'm trying to start an animation after the first animation completes, but I don't know how to do it. I want to make the text go to the top of the page after 2 seconds after the first animation. Here is my code. Thanks :)

CSS:

```
    @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Condensed:300');

body {
    background-image: url("img/new_y_c_grad.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}

.entryText {
    color: white;
    font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 500;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 260px 0;
    font-size: 50px;

}

.animate {
    animation-duration: 1.2s;
    animation-fill-mode: both;
    animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.2, 0.3, 0.25, 0.9);
}

.delay-150 {
    animation-delay: 150ms;
}

@keyframes anim-fade-in-up {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: translate3d(0, 30px, 0)
    }
    50% {
        opacity: 0.5;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: none
    }
}


.anim-fade-in-up {
    animation-name: anim-fade-in-up
}
```

And HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
        <title>Blank App</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">

        <h1 class="entryText animate anim-fade-in-up delay-150">Animation here</h1>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use the same keyframe to do both animations, like this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RACCH/m5btovjp/)

```
.animate {
   animation-duration: 4s;
   animation-fill-mode: both; 
   animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.2, 0.3, 0.25, 0.9);
}

@keyframes anim-fade-in-up {
0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translate3d(0, 30px, 0)
}
25% {
    opacity: 0.5;
}
50% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: none;
    padding-top:260px;   
}
100% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: none;
    padding-top:20px;
}
```

}

And increase the animation duration

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you very much.

Comment: you can use a list of animations on same element, this is not the best answer.

Answer (score 13):

have a look at this pen: http://codepen.io/TunderScripts/pen/ggOgWz

the css

```
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: red;
  animation: example 4s linear, 4s dude 4s linear;
}

@keyframes example {
  0% {
    background-color: red;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
  }
  25% {
    background-color: blue;
    left: 0px;
    top: 200px;
  }
  50% {
    background-color: green;
    left: 200px;
    top: 200px;
  }
  75% {
    background-color: yellow;
    left: 200px;
    top: 0px;
  }
  100% {
    background-color: red;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
  }
}

@keyframes dude {
  0% {
    background-color: red;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
  }
  100% {
    background-color: cyan;
    left: 0px;
    top: 200px;
  }
}
```

You can create how many animations you want and you can stack them by using delay, even overlap. Read this to get a more complex view of what those parameters mean https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/a/animation/ . have a nice day! Keep up the code clean!